# "Process finished with exit code 0" takes a long time to appear after code has been executed

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

I am using Python 3.8.0 and PyCharm and have noticed that on my particular script, the IDE finishes all the code execution (as evidenced by console print statements) but then takes upto 15-20 seconds before showing "Process finished with exit code 0" message. I am assuming its taking some effort for Python to release the memory or shut down the thread?

This has only recently started to occur so its not an IDE-specific issue.

I am concerned there might be a hidden memory leak or such given that I am using functools' lru_cache on a few expensive functions.

Are there any tools I can use to diagnose this issue?

Comment: What OS and version?

Comment: @Stephen Rauch Windows 10

Comment: I have also has some slow code issues with Python 3.8 on Windows.  Have you tried Python 3.7?

Comment: Just upgraded to 3.8 from 3.7 actually. Will revert back to 3.7 and test again.